# Why does imblearn works with jupyter notebook python 2 but not 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, pipeline, imblearn

I'm trying to run a code, but i get an error.
If i have the kernel on python 2 then imblearn works smoothly, but pipe_grid doesn't work. When i switch to python 3, pipe_grid works but imblearn stops working. I didn't share the code because it is long and these 2 are at different parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd don't have high enough score to comment, so it's going to be an answer: [imbalanced-learn](https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/), if that's to what you're referring, works perfectly fine on Python 3.6+. If you're on Python 3.6 or above everything should run smoothly... unless your code needs fixing. Mind that some things have changed between 2 and 3.

You need to share your code if we are to help you, but make sure to cut it to a reproducible example.